# How much liquid nitrogen is required for Maglev trains?

Tags: superconductivity

I understand magnets require cooling to achieve supermagnetivity. How much of liquid nitrogen do Maglevs carry with them? How much is required to keep them cool? What is liquid nitrogen consumption per distance traveled?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a little like asking how much gas does it take to run your car. It depends on the car.

Comment: The purpose of liquid nitrogen is to keep things cold. It doesn't run the run train directly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer.* It's more of an extended comment.

> Magnets require cooling to achieve supermagnetivity.

"Supermagnetivity" is not a word that anybody uses. You might be thinking of [*superconducting magnets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet). Or, you might be thinking of the [*Meissner effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect) in which a mass of superconducting material can be made to levitate in a powerful magnetic field.

In any case, the majority of the maglev trains that have been built so far do not use any superconductors at all. Although, there do appear to be a few that use liquid nitrogen temperature superconductors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev#Technology

* I don't know where you would look to find out how much liquid nitrogen they consume.